# React Native - Navigation goes to another page on refresh

Tags: react-native

I'm building an app which will require a user to accept terms and conditions. Currently I navigate to the terms and conditions with a `NavigatorUtil.navigate`.

If the user accepts the terms it will set the terms to accepted like so:

```
agreePressed() {
    const user = this.props.navigation.getParam('user');
    user['termsAgreed'] = true;
    user['termsVersion'] = t('common:documents:Version');
    NavigatorUtil.navigate('CreateProfile', {user: user, accepted: true});
  }
```

However when I refresh without accepting the terms, I still go to the next page. How can I prevent this behaviour?